# Using a char array as the file name in C with fopen()

Tags: c, arrays, file, char, fopen

I'm writing a program in C designed to allow a user to input the name of a file so that the program can read the contents of that file. The input must be in the format "/i:", which means that I have to strip off the first three characters to obtain the file name.

I'm storing the file name in an array of characters with a preset length (because I don't know how long of a file name the user will input). The commands I'm using are:

```
achBaseOutput[100];
FILE * InputFile

//Instruct users on input

fgets(achBaseOutput, 100, stdin);

//Strips first three characters, scoots file name to start at achBaseOutput[0]

InputFile = fopen(achBaseOutput, "r");
```

When I execute the code, I get an error box that says:

```
Debug Assertion Failed!
File: fgets.c
Line 57
Expression: (str != NULL)
```

Unfortunately, the input format of the file name isn't up to me, so I can't change the /i: formatting for the input.

How can I format the input string so that fopen accepts it as a valid argument?

Comment: What does `fgets()` return?  What is the value of the string that fails?

Comment: The error indicates the problem is with `fgets`, specifically `achBaseOutput` may be null. Can you provide the code which initializes it?

Comment: @AndrewHenle: If he gets an assertion fault in `fgets`, the function is likely not returning, but the program terminates.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. The snippet shown should not generate this behaviour (presuming `achBaseOutput` is a `char [100]`). It also is not related to your question. See [ask].

Comment: I've been giving fgets() file names of local files (for instance, after the prompt I'll type "test" followed by hitting enter.

Comment: The code that initializes it is:


    char achBaseOutput[100];

Comment: @Olaf: I'll rephrase the question. How can I format the input string _once it is input by the user_ so that fopen() accepts it as a valid argument?

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. So, I've got the contents of achBaseOutput[] (after passing it "/i:bob )to be:  

    ['b', 'o', 'b', '\0', '','' ,'', etc]  

It's still giving me the same error. Thoughts?

Comment: See the last comment, he apparently asks about the error. There is not even some code for the splitting. To resolve the error, there is just not enough information given, which is the reason to ask for a MCVE **before** providing a likely wrong answer. This is a rule for good reasons. And now, as you post a unrelated "answer", you blame _me_ for telling you? You really had a bad day, had you?

Comment: @user1536030: Please just follow site-rules and provide the relevant code  in a short, complete program. Apparently the "answer below does not help, but we cannot help if we don't see the **actual** code. The snippets shown clearly don't even compile and - as I wrote - cannot generate this error.

Answer (score 1):

First you must define the array properly, with a type

```
char achBaseOutput[100];
```

The library function `fgets` retains any `newline` you typed (or was in the file) at the end of the line.

It can be removed like this, (needs `#include <string.h>`):

```
achBaseOutput [ strcspn(achBaseOutput, "\r\n") ] = 0;   // remove trailing newline etc
```

You can ignore, rather than remove, the first 3 characters by opening the file like this:

```
InputFile = fopen(achBaseOutput + 3, "r");
```

Comment: I don't see this answering the error either. The problem is apparently a _null pointer_ for `str to `fgets`. But as we don't get the relevant code, how should we answer?

Comment: @Olaf I assumed the error is in the unseen code `//Strips first three characters, scoots file name to start at achBaseOutput[0]` and this answer shows how to simply prepare and pass the filename. OP also seems unaware how `fgets` works.

Comment: @Olaf the question is *"How can I format the input string so that fopen accepts it as a valid argument?"* and this answers it.

Comment: Considering the text of the assertion, I strongly disagree it is in `fopen`. OP just seems to **think** it is there, but the message clearly tells different. I'm afraid without a MCVe we won't get much further here (and apparently OP is not interested in a proper answer to the **actual** problem).

Comment: "disagree" --> "doubt"

Comment: @Olaf OP in comment says *"I'll rephrase the question. How can I format the input string once it is input by the user so that fopen() accepts it as a valid argument?"* But I agree with you that is a poorly asked question.

Comment: Without any offence to OP intended,but I suspect he really does not know what is going on. Often the way to resolve an error is to ask the right questions. Problem is, he seems not to be interested editing the question. After 3 years onm SO, she really should know better. Too bad.